# In the scheduler of the GHC RTS, why should it mark a capability as free?

Tags: haskell, runtime, scheduling, ghc

When I read through [the GHC Wiki commentary on the scheduler](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Scheduler) I was confused about this section:

> One reason behind marking a Capability
>   as free when it is handed over is to
>   support fast callouts. When making a
>   safe foreign call we have to release
>   the Capability, and therefore hand it
>   over to another worker thread. If the
>   foreign call is short, we don't want
>   to incur the cost of a context switch
>   on returning, but since we marked the
>   Capability as free there's a good
>   chance the returning Task will be able
>   to re-acquire it immediately and
>   continue. The worker that we woke up
>   will find that the Capability is
>   owned, and go back to sleep again
>   **(this may incur a double context
>   switch if there are no free CPUs on
>   which to run the worker, however).**

My question:
For the bold sentence, what indeed will lead to the "Double context switch", with or without marking a capability as free. Furthermore, what are the two "switches" if they happen -- from who1 to who2, then who2 to who3?

Comment: Hello Wu, you may get a more direct answer by consulting cvs-ghc@haskell.org, glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org, or the #ghc IRC channel on Freenode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially answered here: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/cvs-ghc/2011-May/062287.html (a copy: http://markmail.org/message/2q6fjthw2wvof244?q=switch+list:org.haskell.cvs-ghc&page=2)